# Laravel shows wrong date when casting from timestamp to date:Y/n/j

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using laravel casts inside my model to cast my timestamps to date:Y/n/j. But laravel casts it to wrong date.

model:

```
class Diary {
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'date:Y/n/j',
    ];
```

app.php:

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Tokyo',
```

php.ini:

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Tokyo"
```

mysql:

```
select  * from diaries;
+----+-------+---------------------+
| id | diary | created_at          | 
+----+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | 愛    | 2021-06-08 01:00:01 |
+----+-------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

output after casting:

```
$firstDiary= Diary::first();
$firstDiary->toJson();

...    

// It must be 2021/6/8
'created_at' => 2021/6/7
```

I already did:

> php artisan config:cache
>
> date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

If I change created_at from "2021-06-08 01:00:01" to something greater than "2021-06-08 8:59:59", it shows correctly.
I'm using laravel 8, mysql 8 and php 8. So probably [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization) is not my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: When you changed the ```'timezone' => 'Asia/Tokyo',``` in app.php then you stop serving your project and re-serve it, or no? If no, please test that.

Comment: I’m running this project in localhost

Comment: Ok. You served your project with this command: ```php artisan serve```. Please stop that serve and re-run ```php artisan serve``` again and test that date please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Laravel 7.0, when calling `toJson` the framework uses Carbon's `toJson` method behind the scenes which produces ISO-8601 compatible dates which are always expressed in UTC. Therefore, I'm guessing your timezone is converted to UTC before the date is casted to your required format and thus something like this is happening:

```php
\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2021-06-08 01:00:01', 'Asia/Tokyo')->timezone('UTC')->format('Y/n/j'); // 2021/6/7
\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2021-06-08 08:59:59', 'Asia/Tokyo')->timezone('UTC')->format('Y/n/j'); // 2021/6/7
\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2021-06-08 09:00:00', 'Asia/Tokyo')->timezone('UTC')->format('Y/n/j'); // 2021/6/8
```

I suggest you to keep storing and returing everything in UTC and converting to the required timezone at the last possible moment to keep everything managable. Although, if you insist on storing everything in `Asia\Tokyo` and returning it in the same timezone and doing no conversions, then overriding `serilizeDate` function for your models should do the trick as described in an earlier upgrade guide:

[Laravel 7.0 upgrade guide: Date Serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization)